# jQuery: animate opacity not working when emulating toggling with .on() and .off()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to develop a form that will appear when the user clicks a button, and disappears when the user clicks outside the form.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4gavkfd/

```
var app = {

init: function() {
    $("#button").on("click", function(){
        app.opaq();
        $("#button").off("click");
    });
},

opaq: function() {
    $("#overlay").css('z-index', '10000');
    $("#overlay").animate({
        opacity: 1  
    }, 500);    
    $(document).on("click", app.exitFunc);
},

exitFunc: function(e) {
    var gg = $("#overlay");
    var c = gg.css('opacity');
    if (c == 1 && !gg.is(e.target) && gg.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        app.fade();
        app.init();
    }
},

fade: function() {
    $("#overlay").animate({
        opacity: 0  
    }, 500).delay(50, function() {
        $("#overlay").css('z-index', '-10000')
    });
    $(document).off("click");        
},  

}

app.init();
```

This works fine when you first click the button and remove `#overlay` by clicking outside of it.

However, when you try to make `#overlay` reappear by clicking the button again, the opacity is not being animated, although the function itself is being called properly. I feel like the problem isn't my use of `.on()` or `.off()`, but maybe I'm missing something with `.animate()`? I don't know why it's running the first time but subsequent clicks do not work.

Comment: `.delay()` second argument  function ? , not `queue` name , string http://api.jquery.com/delay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the logic by using a single click event on the document, and determining the target of the click:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  var id= e.target.id;

  if(id==='button' || id==='overlay') {
    $('#overlay')
      .stop()
      .css('zIndex', 1)
      .animate({opacity: 1})
  }
  else {
    $('#overlay')
      .stop()
      .animate({opacity: 0},
               function() {$('#overlay').css('zIndex', -1)}
              );
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uuekzykj/)

Comment: Nice, thank you. I also added `$("#overlay").has(e.target).length !== 0` in the if statement so that the overlay div won't disappear when you click on its child nodes.

Comment: Great, I should have considered that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `animate`, I usually use CSS transitions and jQuery `toggleClass()`. I created a CSS class called `opaque`, which sets the opacity to 1 smoothly over the course of .5 seconds. If you click on anything in the HTML except for the button or the `#overlay` element, the `#overlay` element will become transparent. If you click the button, the element's opacity will be smoothly toggled. This doesn't follow the code structure that you used before, but it should accomplish what you were looking for. Additionally, you can add attributes to the `.opaque` class to make them change, as well.

JavaScript:

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#overlay").toggleClass("opaque");    
});
$("#overlay").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
$("#container").click(function(){
    $("#overlay").removeClass("opaque");
});
```

CSS:

```
.opaque {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition: opacity .5s ease;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/z4gavkfd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Note, Try substituting second argument to `.delay()` ; `String`:`queueName` for `function` . See [.delay( duration [, queueName ] )](http://api.jquery.com/delay/#delay-duration-queueName) .

> **.delay( duration [, queueName ] )**
>
> **duration Type**:
>
> Integer An integer
>   indicating the number of milliseconds to delay execution of the next
>   item in the queue.
>
> **queueName Type**:
>
> String A string containing the name
>   of the queue. Defaults to fx, the standard effects queue.

also , removing `app.init();` from `exitFunc` , which appear to set additional `click` event at `#button` ?

```
var app = {

    init: function() {
        $("#button").on("click", function(){
            app.opaq();
        });
    },

    opaq: function() {
        $("#overlay").css('z-index', '10000');
        $("#overlay").fadeTo(500, 1, "linear"); 
        $("body *")
        .not("#overlay")
        .on("click.q", app.exitFunc);
    },

    exitFunc: function(e) {
        var gg = $("#overlay");
        var c = gg.css('opacity');
        if (c == 1 && !gg.is(e.target) && gg.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            app.fade();
        }
    },

    fade: function() {
        $("#overlay")        
        .fadeTo(500, 0, "linear", function() {
          $(this).css('z-index', '-10000')
        });

        $("body *")
        .not("#overlay").off("click.q")       
    },  

}

app.init();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z4gavkfd/3/